# Run lib callback function inside react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, react-helmet

I am trying to integrate react with a payment gateway.

The payment has its own library, so, I included the library in `index.html` file in the `head` tag

```
 <script src="url.js" data-error="errorCallback"
    data-cancel="cancelCallback" data-complete="completeCallback" data-timeout="timeoutCallback">
</script>
```

Then I call the callback function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorCallback(error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    function cancelCallback() {
      console.log('Payment cancelled');
    }
    function completeCallback() {
      console.log('Payment complete');
    }
    function timeoutCallback() {
      console.log("Timeout")
    }
  </script>
```

My question is, how can I call these 4 functions inside a react component?
The purpose I want to show a successful dialog when the `completeCallback` trigger.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom events to listen the activity from these method. Create and dispatch them from these methods and add listener to them in your react components.

In your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorCallback(error) {
      const errorCallbackUrl = new CreateEvent('errorCallbackUrl', {detail: 'yourdata'});
      window.dispatchEvent(errorCallbackUrl)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  </script>
```

In your react component bind them like this:

```
   window.addEventListener('errorCallbackUrl', (data) => {
        // do something in your component
        // call methods/update state
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

Similarly, you can follow it backwards to do the same thing in index.html from the components to call any methods.